# Access ArcCatalog Window through ArcPY

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcpy, arccatalog

I want to create a button in ArcCatalog that takes the metadata from the selected file in ArcCatalog and prints it to a text file. The metadata extraction part is done, and I have succssfully tested it on a number of GIS datasets. However, I cannot figure out how to get information about the currently selected item in ArcCatalog.

Is this possible in ArcCatalog? I expected for there to be something simple, and similar to the Arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT"), but I can't find anything.

I would prefer to keep this in python, but an ArcObjects solution is also possible (just not preferable)

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the export button in the items description tab, just curious?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS? The `pythonaddins` module, as of 10.3, has a function to fetch the currently selected Catalog Window's path.

Comment: We are using 10.2 at my office, so that is good to know. The [current tool for 10.2](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000021000000) looks like it is close, but yeah, it doesn't seem to work with ArcCatalog

Comment: The export function would work, perhaps, but based on the workflow we want, it is a bit more work than necessary. I might consider it though

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to deploy your script in a toolbox, which you could access from ArcCatalog. The script, which you expose as a tool in a custom-made toolbox will allow your users to select a datatset and run the script on it. Should you need to run the script on several datatset , you users can use the built-in batch mode (present by default in all tools).

Comment: That's a good suggestion, thanks! Its not the exact workflow we want, but it could be an easy interim solution